# How do i call a code at each frame?

Tags: android

In my current Android project I'm using the default files for a new project.

I noticed that in `MainActivity.java` you define what to do when certian things happen. So for example, if you'd wanna execute a piece of code when the application is being created, you'd use `onCreate`.

So I was curious, what is the equivalent for when a new frame is being drawn on screen?

The goal is to have it execute a few lines of code 60 times a second or so.

Comment: What is drawing the frames?

Comment: I don't know. I'm assuming that the screen is being updated automatically for me via the OS. There is no call for an "redraw screen" function in  the default MainActivity.java

Comment: @Omrii If you are doing some type of animation you'll want to look at custom view: https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html

Comment: I'm not sure what you're up to, but you may want to look at https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html#loops